# The best way to do insertions in Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm actually trying to make an insertion in a Laravel application but I'm not sure how to do it. I have two differents lines of code. One line is calling a model 
    (`$reservation = (new \App\Reservation)->create($form_data);`) and the other one make an insertion directly into the database
    (`DB::table('reservations')->insert([
            'numero_semaine' => $request->nombreSemaine,
            'date'           => $request->dateReservation,
            'heure_debut'    => $request->heureDebut,
            'heure_fin'      => $request->heureFin,
            'horaire_id'      => $request->horaire,
            'local_id'         => $request->local,
            'event_id'         => $request->event
        ]);`).

My question is : What is the best way to make an insertion ? I'm not sure about removing the     `DB::table(...)->insert(...)` but I'd like to know what is the difference between this method and the other one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"? That depends on your use case. For example, if your model runs any validation checks, you should not circumvent them by inserting directly into the database

Answer (score 1):

You can create model, migration and Controller with php make:model Reservation -a

The best way is with a Model, you need one model Reservation, php artisan make:model Reservation

and in your model:

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reservations';

   protected $fillable = [
      'numero_semaine', 'date', 'heure_debut', 'heure_fin','horaire_id', 
      'local_id', 'event_id'
    ];
```

Create with this methos inside Model:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->all();
   $validator = $this->validator($data);

   if($validator->fails()){
            return Response::json(array(
                'succes' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
            ), 400);
        }

   Reservation::create([
     'numero_semaine' => $data->nombreSemaine,
        'date'           => $data->dateReservation,
        'heure_debut'    => $data->heureDebut,
        'heure_fin'      => $data->heureFin,
        'horaire_id'      => $data->horaire,
        'local_id'         => $data->local,
        'event_id'         => $data->event

   ]);

  }

  protected function validator(array $data){
    return Validator::make($data,[
        'numero_semaine' => ['required', 'numeric' etc...],
        'date' => ['required' etc...],
          'next value...' => [ conditionals ]
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you. And is it possible to do this operation for multiple tables without creating multiple controllers ? Or do I have to make a controller for each creation method ?

Comment: Controller is for example, you can create on Model, when you make Model, you have one function create, when you need more tables you can make differents models, i can edit my response

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what about the amount of controllers ? Do you usually make multiple controllers and then put some methods inside them or do you make only one controller with all the methods inside ? I need to put datas in four different tables. It's for getting a good practice in Laravel.  And sorry if my english seems bad.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - it does not answer whether direct database updates or updates through a model are "better"

Comment: Usually i make CRUD on model, and in controller i manipulate data, or pass data to view

Comment: That's not the reply you gave to Bindash with your example ?